# Group rows by datediff and then use diff function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table in PostgreSQL with timestamp column `created_at` and integer column `user_id`.

```
id | created_at | user_id
1 | 2019-10-14 09:26:53.813 | 1
2 | 2019-10-14 09:26:54.813 | 1
3 | 2019-10-14 09:46:53.813 | 1
4 | 2019-10-14 09:46:54.813 | 2
5 | 2019-10-14 09:46:55.813 | 1
6 | 2019-10-14 09:46:56.813 | 1
7 | 2019-10-14 09:46:57.813 | 2
```

Each row represents some action from user. I need to calculate average user session length. Session is defined as group of actions with time difference less than 10 minutes. When there is difference 10 minutes or more between two user actions, new session started.

I was thinking about:

1. Group rows by `user_id`.
2. Group rows (somehow) by difference between current and next item for single user. (to get sessions)
3. Calculate diff between first and last row in one group (session). (to get session lengths)
4. Calculate average session length. (to get average session length)

But I am not able to write it in SQL.

Could you give me some advice/example how can be this done in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=668d7963299d2c42a41971c1c25f3cf9)

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    AVG(diff)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        user_id,
        group_id,
        first_value(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, group_id ORDER BY created_at DESC)
            - first_value(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, group_id ORDER BY created_at) as diff
    FROM (
        SELECT
            id, created_at, user_id,
            SUM(group_id) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at) AS group_id
        FROM (
            SELECT
                *,
                (created_at 
                    - lag(created_at, 1, created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at)
                    > interval '10 minutes')::int AS group_id
            FROM
                mytable   
        )s
    )s
)s
GROUP BY user_id
```

1. `(created_at - lag(created_at, 1, created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at) > interval '10 minutes')::int AS group_id`: the `lag()` [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) takes the `created_at` value from the previous record (second parameter: step length, third parameter: default value if no previous record == current value) within the ordered `user_id` partition (group). Then the difference between current `created_at` value an the previous one is calculated. If this value is > 10 minutes, the result is `true`; `false` otherwise. This boolean can be casted into an `int` value, which results in `0` or `1`
2. Cumulative `SUM()` over the `0`/`1` values, which results in `group_id`s for every new session per `user_id`
3. The first created_at timestamp per `user_id` and session `group_id` can be get by `first_value()` window function, the last one by `first_value()` and `DESC` order. The difference gives you the length of each session. The `DISTINCT` clause is used, because the difference value is put onto every record. But we need this only once.
4. Finally, you can group and `AVG()` this difference for the users.

Comment: Did this help? If so, please do not forget to mark one answer as accepted to close the question (check mark at the top left corner of the relevant answer). Otherwise, please tell us what to change.

Comment: I am getting the same average times for all users. Group 1 for User 1 and User 2 has the same diff. I guess it has something to do with that first_value functions, as in this function is used only group_id and both users has sessions with group_id === 1.

Comment: As shown in the fiddle above the users get different averages. What is the difference to your real data?

Comment: Yes, but in the second query from the end, both rows with group_id === 0 has the same ?column? value. I tried to change "(7, '2019-10-14 09:46:57.813', 2)", to "(7, '2019-10-14 09:46:58.813', 2)", so I added one second for user_2 group_0, and both records, user_1 group_0 and user_2 group_0 has changed to 00:20:05. Only length of user_2 group_0 should change.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fca0ae5847481d7e0a300bed8b76dd90

It is the same as yours, only one row in insert is changed.

Comment: You can see it in the table, where are first_value and last_value. These values are the same for user_id == 1 && group_id == 0....and for user_id == 2 && group_id == 0.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=668d7963299d2c42a41971c1c25f3cf9 Yes, you are right. Forget to add the user_id into the partition. Fixed :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `lag()` and a cumulative count of where the differences exceed your threshhold:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) filter (where prev_created_at is null or prev_created_at < created_at - interval '10 minute'
                       ) over (partition by user_id order by created_at) as session_number
from (select t.*,
             lag(created_at) over (partition by user_id order by created_at) as prev_created_at
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: This solution is working, but it does not do everything I needed. It is increasing session_number for every session of user, but it does not calculate lengths of these sessions and does not calculate average length too. The same result as this can be achieved with inner-part of the answer from S-Man.

Comment: @tomasgabrs . . . I'm surprised that you don't see how  to use `group by` to get the information you want.  The harder part of the problem is assigning the sessions.